# You have an error in your SQL syntax; when try to submit form

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '','1','7','123tw')' at line 2

I got the above error when submitting the form.

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    $branch=$_SESSION['branch'];
    include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
        $name = $_POST['prod_name'];
        $price = $_POST['prod_price'];
        $desc = $_POST['prod_desc'];
        $supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
        $reorder = $_POST['reorder'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        //$quantity = $_POST['prod_qty'];
        $serialn = $_POST['serialn'];

        $query2=mysqli_query($con,"select * from product where prod_name='$name' and branch_id='$branch'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $count=mysqli_num_rows($query2);

            if ($count>0)
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Product already exist!');</script>";
                echo "<script>document.location='product.php'</script>";  
            }
            else
            {   

                $pic = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                if ($pic=="")
                {
                    $pic="default.gif";
                }
                else
                {
                    $pic = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                    $type = $_FILES["image"]["type"];
                    $size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
                    $temp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
                    $error = $_FILES["image"]["error"];

                    if ($error > 0)
                    {
                        die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
                        }
                    else{
                        if($size > 100000000000) //conditions for the file
                            {
                            die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
                            }
                    else
                          {
                        move_uploaded_file($temp, "../dist/uploads/".$pic);
                          }
                        }
                }   

                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO product(prod_name,prod_price,prod_desc,prod_pic,cat_id,reorder,supplier_id,branch_id,serialn)
                VALUES('$name','$price','$desc','$pic','$category', $reorder','$supplier','$branch','$serialn')")or die(mysqli_error($con));

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully added new product!');</script>";
                          echo "<script>document.location='product.php'</script>";  
            }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Forget about this issue, start with refactoring your code using Prepared Statements (which will change your queries) and your issue will most likely be solved in the process. Don''t waste time debugging insecure code that you _really_ need to update anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a single quote before `$reorder'` ?

Comment: Take note of others' comments about SQL injection issues and other matters!

Answer (score 0):

Error in your SQL INSERT Query.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO product(prod_name,prod_price,prod_desc,prod_pic,cat_id,reorder,supplier_id,branch_id,serialn)
VALUES('$name','$price','$desc','$pic','$category','$reorder','$supplier','$branch','$serialn')")or die(mysqli_error($con))
```

try now..

Comment: That won't change anything. You do know that you can echo variables inside double quoted strings, right? And if you look at the query that fails, it's the INSERT further down, not the above.

Comment: edited .. Error is in Insert Query at $reorder. You put $reorder' instead of '$reorder'

Comment: Another thing, you should _not_ concatenate queries. You should use Prepared Statements. At least if you don't want to be vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `'` before `$reorder` try this code

```
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO product(prod_name, prod_price, prod_desc ,prod_pic, cat_id, reorder, supplier_id, branch_id, serialn) VALUES ('$name', '$price', '$desc', '$pic', '$category', '$reorder', '$supplier', '$branch', '$serialn')")or die(mysqli_error($con))or die(mysqli_error($con));
```